# How to change html elements automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I was just reading about scraping with dom and had a thought. Is it possible to change web elements automatically when you visit a page? Ex :

[image]

However I want to change it to something like this:

[image]

Is this possible to do automatically without any extensions for web browsers?

Comment: Without extensions, no. Unless you want to type the script in to the console every time you visit the page. Check out Tampermonkey and http://userscripts.org

Comment: can i write a php script to this? (Sorry not very experienced)

Comment: Well you're asking two questions here. If you want to do scraping then yes, you'd have to do it server side, so PHP, ASP.Net, Node etc would be useful. If all you want to do is change the page layout to your own liking on your own machine, then use the extension I mentioned above

Comment: I looked at this [link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and under How to modify html elements they have some code. How do I run that?

Comment: You need to run that on a server. Also note that that's effectively using a proxy. What exactly is it you're trying to do here, and why

Comment: I am trying to create a setting for kids where swear words will get erased or eliminated. Example: F*** become -----

Answer (score 0):

You hit ctrl+shidt+i to open inspect element.

They you find the element you want and get the id:

```
 <a id="nav-jobs" href="jobs">
     Jobs
 </a>
```

and in the console tab you type:

```
document.getElementById('nav-jobs').innerHTML = 'Hello';
```

Comment: I tried using your method but when I refresh the page, it goes back to normal. Can I eliminate this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any browser extensions you could write a proxy server and redirect any traffic from your browser to the proxy. This is possible in php, too. As a starter you could use [miniProxy](https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy).

But that could be a very ambitious project.

Comment: I went to this [link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and found a piece of code under how to modify html elements. Will this work?

Comment: @WossmathPrep You will need the DOM parser when you try to manipulate the HTML code. But you will need the proxy too as man-in-the-middle between the client (browser) and the web servers.